# PHP inserting values bug

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I dont understand what is wrong with this array and why it does not work, when any other times it worked...

Its simple, i do a foreach loop and insert values to an array:

```
$insert = [];

foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {

   $insert[$i] = [
        'id_customer' => $row[0],
        'id_shop_group' => $row[1],
        `id_shop` => $row[2],
    ];
}
```

The array generated is:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id_customer' => string '14' (length=2)
      'id_shop_group' => string '1' (length=1)
      '' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I dont understand... I am creating my own keys, it should be added to the array, but it isnt... what is the problem?

Comment: You're using `\`` for `id_shop`, rather than `'` like with `id_customer` and `id_shop_group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the use of the wrong `'`. In the third array key you used ` instead of `'`.

Comment: fck my life.... Thanks!